# Copy records of MySQL table to the next week

Tags: php, mysql

I want to copy data from MySQL table to next week basing on specific conditions. Schematic representation of the problem is given in the the figure below.

[image: Schematic representation of the problem]

My table consists of records that represent calendar terms with range of 30 min. All records start either from H:00 or H:30. The structure of table is given in the following script (which matches the given figure):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `field1` INTEGER,
  `flag` INTEGER,
  `startDate` VARCHAR(256),
  `endDate` VARCHAR(256)  
);

INSERT INTO Table1
  (`id`, `field1`, `flag`, `startDate`, `endDate`)
VALUES
(1,4,0,'2021-02-10 09:00:00','2021-02-10 09:30:00'),
(2,3,0,'2021-02-12 10:00:00','2021-02-12 10:30:00'),
(3,3,1,'2021-02-13 12:00:00','2021-02-13 12:30:00'),
(4,3,0,'2021-02-15 11:00:00','2021-02-15 11:30:00'),
(5,17,0,'2021-02-22 11:00:00','2021-02-22 11:30:00');
```

I would like to copy pattern of data from one week to the next week (no recursive call, just one copy).
Only records where `flag=0` should be copied (only green cells). If in the same term in the next week already exists another record, such copy should be skipped. It doesn't actually matter whether the copy of record N.4 is skipped or the next week record is overwritten, but there cannot be two records that share the same term. So, the values of fields other than `startDate` and `endDate` are not important.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/895afe)

Comment: To prevent duplicates just make dates unique. Then execute INSERT IGNORE or INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY, depending on which is more appropriate.

Comment: Given that all events are 30 minutes , I really don't understand the point of end dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using an insert select

```
INSERT INTO Table1
  (`id`, `field1`, `flag`, `startDate`, `endDate`)
select `id`, `field1`, `flag`, date_add(`startDate`, INTERVAL 7 DAY),  date_add(`endDate`, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
from Table1 
where flag=0
```

if you want avoid duplicated row insert  you should add the distinct clause in select

```
INSERT INTO Table1
  (`id`, `field1`, `flag`, `startDate`, `endDate`)
select  DISTINCT `id`, `field1`, `flag`, date_add(`startDate`, INTERVAL 7 DAY),  date_add(`endDate`, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
from Table1 
where flag=0
```

for the duplicated  record  could be  you just need  that there is not record  for the destination day

```
INSERT INTO Table1
  (`id`, `field1`, `flag`, `startDate`, `endDate`)
select `id`, `field1`, `flag`, date_add(`startDate`, INTERVAL 7 DAY),  date_add(`endDate`, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
from Table1 
where flag=0 
AND `startDate` <>date_add(`startDate`, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this potentially create 2 records with the same date?

Comment: this just select and insert  .. if there are two record  are select two record  and inserted  two record . .. in fthe user want avoid this case could add DISTINCT in select

Comment: Thank you, but that creates two records at position 5. I updated figure for better clearness. In addition, I forgot to mention that ```id``` is primary key with auto counter.

Comment: @scaisEdge Could you please elaborate that with DISTINCT in select?

Comment: @FlashGordon  answer  updated  with distinct

Comment: @scaisEdge Thank you, but there is no difference - it still creates two records. Or, I don't understand it. However, the approach is useful because I just removed the duplicates afterwards. By duplicates I assumed all records that have the same ```startDate```.

Comment: @FlashGordon  answer  updated  with a suggestion for avoid dup on start_date

Comment: @scaisEdge isn't the last condition always true?

Comment: ..in you sample img  not ..  .. the query is for select all the row with flag=0 and the destination date is not 7 day from start ..  for avoid 4 is copie also and have 4 and 5